# How to use chdir system function

Tags: c, fgets, cd, chdir

I am trying to use chdir to change the working directory of my process. Say I have an apple directory in my current directory. Why is it that when I input apple in the prompt the returned result is -1? Is it because when I enter apple, the '\n' character is also put at the end of the string?
Besides, what is the meaning of changing directory if I could just use a variable to store it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(void){
    char path[256];
    fgets(path, 256, stdin);
    printf("%s", path);
    int result = chdir(path);
    if(result != 0){
        printf("%d\n", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: For `chdir()` please see here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html or type `man 2 chdir` on your console.

Comment: your correct about the 'path' variable containing a newline.  There are several ways to eliminate the newline.  I use : `char *newline = strstr( path, "\n");  if (newline) { *newline = '\0';}`

Comment: Note: since a program is run in a separate process, when the program exits, the current working directory will be the same as before the program was run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fgets()` <strike>suffixes the result with</strike> might (if no `EOF` had been received) read a new-line (`\n` on IXish systems) and passing this to `chdir()` makes the latter choke as the directory name to change to most likley does not carry a trailing new-line.

From [`man fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) (*Italics by me*):

> **fgets()** reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. *If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.*

---

A note on debugging: If you'd put the "string" to print (as read by `fgets()`) in quotes like this

```
printf("'%s'", path);
```

you might have noticed the trailing `\n`.

Comment: I see, but can you tell me what does chdir really do? Because I am writing an assignment to implement the cd function of the shell?

Comment: @lplouis: `chdir()` changes the process's current work directory.

Comment: Nitpick: `fgets(3)` does not *suffix the result with `\n`*. It merely copies it from input to the buffer. If `EOF` is reached without a `\n`, the buffer won't have a trailing newline - your answer seems to say otherwise.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: Corrected.